# Change stepper's line color flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change color of line in stepper, Look at the below picture

[image: stepper]

my try here :

```
Theme(
        data: ThemeData(canvasColor: whiteColor),
        child: Stepper(
          type: StepperType.horizontal,
          steps: getSteps(),
          currentStep: currentStep,
          elevation: 2,
        ),
      ),
```

Please help to continue my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flutter Default stepper Line has Static color use so can't change this.
chack below Image.

[image]

[image]

Here https://fluttergems.dev/stepper mention many stepper package used as you want.

Comment: Actually, I took a look at the source code, and I don't think this is the correct line.

Comment: please see the updated answer. there is some flutter code that uses static color not use theme color not we can change this.

Comment: Got it.  I have to use another package.

Answer (score 1):

Let me be short and clear.

**TO CHANGE STEPPER LINE COLOR**

Unfortunately, the Flutter code for the `Stepper` does not support the change of the Stepper line color (`_buildLine`) and more.

*So I created a custom stepper called `CusStepper` that uses `CusStep`*

**NOTE:** This `CusStepper` has the same properties and behaves like the normal `Stepper` with the only difference of `lineColor` property.

**Steps on how to use the `CusStepper`**

1. Create a new .dart file to store the `CusStepper` code
2. Paste the code below for the `CusStepper` in the file.
3. Import it to the file you want to use it in.
4. Finally change the stepper line color with the `lineColor` params. on the `CusStepper`

**`CusStepper` code to paste in the .dart file created in step 1**

```dart
// THIS IS A CUSTOM STEPPER THAT ADDS LINE COLOR
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum CusStepState {
  indexed,
  editing,
  complete,
  disabled,
  error,
}

enum CusStepperType {
  vertical,
  horizontal,
}

@immutable
class ControlsDetails {
  const ControlsDetails({
    required this.currentStep,
    required this.stepIndex,
    this.onStepCancel,
    this.onStepContinue,
  });
  final int currentStep;
  final int stepIndex;
  final VoidCallback? onStepContinue;
  final VoidCallback? onStepCancel;
  bool get isActive => currentStep == stepIndex;
}

typedef ControlsWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details);

const TextStyle _kStepStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 12.0,
  color: Colors.white,
);
const Color _kErrorLight = Colors.red;
final Color _kErrorDark = Colors.red.shade400;
const Color _kCircleActiveLight = Colors.white;
const Color _kCircleActiveDark = Colors.black87;
const Color _kDisabledLight = Colors.black38;
const Color _kDisabledDark = Colors.white38;
const double _kStepSize = 24.0;
const double _kTriangleHeight = _kStepSize * 0.866025;

@immutable
class CusStep {
  const CusStep({
    required this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    required this.content,
    this.state = CusStepState.indexed,
    this.isActive = false,
    this.label,
  });

  final Widget title;

  final Widget? subtitle;

  final Widget content;

  final CusStepState state;

  final bool isActive;

  final Widget? label;
}

class CusStepper extends StatefulWidget {
  const CusStepper({
    super.key,
    required this.steps,
    this.physics,
    this.type = CusStepperType.vertical,
    this.currentStep = 0,
    this.onStepTapped,
    this.onStepContinue,
    this.onStepCancel,
    this.controlsBuilder,
    this.elevation,
    this.margin,
    this.lineColor = Colors.grey,
  })  : assert(0 <= currentStep && currentStep < steps.length);

  final List<CusStep> steps;

  final ScrollPhysics? physics;

  final CusStepperType type;

  final int currentStep;

  final ValueChanged<int>? onStepTapped;

  final VoidCallback? onStepContinue;

  final VoidCallback? onStepCancel;

  final ControlsWidgetBuilder? controlsBuilder;

  final double? elevation;

  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin;

  final Color lineColor;

  @override
  State<CusStepper> createState() => _CusStepperState();
}

class _CusStepperState extends State<CusStepper> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<GlobalKey> _keys;
  final Map<int, CusStepState> _oldStates = <int, CusStepState>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _keys = List<GlobalKey>.generate(
      widget.steps.length,
      (int i) => GlobalKey(),
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1) {
      _oldStates[i] = widget.steps[i].state;
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CusStepper oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    assert(widget.steps.length == oldWidget.steps.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < oldWidget.steps.length; i += 1) {
      _oldStates[i] = oldWidget.steps[i].state;
    }
  }

  bool _isFirst(int index) {
    return index == 0;
  }

  bool _isLast(int index) {
    return widget.steps.length - 1 == index;
  }

  bool _isCurrent(int index) {
    return widget.currentStep == index;
  }

  bool _isDark() {
    return Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
  }

  bool _isLabel() {
    for (final CusStep step in widget.steps) {
      if (step.label != null) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  Widget _buildLine(bool visible) {
    return Container(
      width: visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      height: 16.0,
      color: widget.lineColor,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCircleChild(int index, bool oldState) {
    final CusStepState state =
        oldState ? _oldStates[index]! : widget.steps[index].state;
    final bool isDarkActive = _isDark() && widget.steps[index].isActive;
    switch (state) {
      case CusStepState.indexed:
      case CusStepState.disabled:
        return Text(
          '${index + 1}',
          style: isDarkActive
              ? _kStepStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black87)
              : _kStepStyle,
        );
      case CusStepState.editing:
        return Icon(
          Icons.edit,
          color: isDarkActive ? _kCircleActiveDark : _kCircleActiveLight,
          size: 18.0,
        );
      case CusStepState.complete:
        return Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: isDarkActive ? _kCircleActiveDark : _kCircleActiveLight,
          size: 18.0,
        );
      case CusStepState.error:
        return const Text('!', style: _kStepStyle);
    }
  }

  Color _circleColor(int index) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    if (!_isDark()) {
      return widget.steps[index].isActive
          ? colorScheme.primary
          : colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38);
    } else {
      return widget.steps[index].isActive
          ? colorScheme.secondary
          : colorScheme.background;
    }
  }

  Widget _buildCircle(int index, bool oldState) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      width: _kStepSize,
      height: _kStepSize,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _circleColor(index),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: _buildCircleChild(
              index, oldState && widget.steps[index].state == CusStepState.error),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTriangle(int index, bool oldState) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      width: _kStepSize,
      height: _kStepSize,
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: _kStepSize,
          height:
              _kTriangleHeight, // Height of 24dp-long-sided equilateral triangle.
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: _TrianglePainter(
              color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: const Alignment(
                  0.0, 0.8), // 0.8 looks better than the geometrical 0.33.
              child: _buildCircleChild(index,
                  oldState && widget.steps[index].state != CusStepState.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(int index) {
    if (widget.steps[index].state != _oldStates[index]) {
      return AnimatedCrossFade(
        firstChild: _buildCircle(index, true),
        secondChild: _buildTriangle(index, true),
        firstCurve: const Interval(0.0, 0.6, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        secondCurve: const Interval(0.4, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        sizeCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        crossFadeState: widget.steps[index].state == CusStepState.error
            ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
            : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
        duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
      );
    } else {
      if (widget.steps[index].state != CusStepState.error) {
        return _buildCircle(index, false);
      } else {
        return _buildTriangle(index, false);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _buildVerticalControls(int stepIndex) {
    if (widget.controlsBuilder != null) {
      return widget.controlsBuilder!(
        context,
        ControlsDetails(
          currentStep: widget.currentStep,
          onStepContinue: widget.onStepContinue,
          onStepCancel: widget.onStepCancel,
          stepIndex: stepIndex,
        ),
      );
    }

    final Color cancelColor;
    switch (Theme.of(context).brightness) {
      case Brightness.light:
        cancelColor = Colors.black54;
        break;
      case Brightness.dark:
        cancelColor = Colors.white70;
        break;
    }

    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = themeData.colorScheme;
    final MaterialLocalizations localizations =
        MaterialLocalizations.of(context);

    const OutlinedBorder buttonShape = RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)));
    const EdgeInsets buttonPadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0);

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 48.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: widget.onStepContinue,
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                  return states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
                      ? null
                      : (_isDark()
                          ? colorScheme.onSurface
                          : colorScheme.onPrimary);
                }),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                  return _isDark() || states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
                      ? null
                      : colorScheme.primary;
                }),
                padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                    buttonPadding),
                shape:
                    const MaterialStatePropertyAll<OutlinedBorder>(buttonShape),
              ),
              child: Text(themeData.useMaterial3
                  ? localizations.continueButtonLabel
                  : localizations.continueButtonLabel.toUpperCase()),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 8.0),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: widget.onStepCancel,
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  foregroundColor: cancelColor,
                  padding: buttonPadding,
                  shape: buttonShape,
                ),
                child: Text(themeData.useMaterial3
                    ? localizations.cancelButtonLabel
                    : localizations.cancelButtonLabel.toUpperCase()),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextStyle _titleStyle(int index) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextTheme textTheme = themeData.textTheme;

    switch (widget.steps[index].state) {
      case CusStepState.indexed:
      case CusStepState.editing:
      case CusStepState.complete:
        return textTheme.bodyLarge!;
      case CusStepState.disabled:
        return textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kDisabledDark : _kDisabledLight,
        );
      case CusStepState.error:
        return textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
        );
    }
  }

  TextStyle _subtitleStyle(int index) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextTheme textTheme = themeData.textTheme;

    switch (widget.steps[index].state) {
      case CusStepState.indexed:
      case CusStepState.editing:
      case CusStepState.complete:
        return textTheme.bodySmall!;
      case CusStepState.disabled:
        return textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kDisabledDark : _kDisabledLight,
        );
      case CusStepState.error:
        return textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
        );
    }
  }

  TextStyle _labelStyle(int index) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextTheme textTheme = themeData.textTheme;

    switch (widget.steps[index].state) {
      case CusStepState.indexed:
      case CusStepState.editing:
      case CusStepState.complete:
        return textTheme.bodyLarge!;
      case CusStepState.disabled:
        return textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kDisabledDark : _kDisabledLight,
        );
      case CusStepState.error:
        return textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
        );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildHeaderText(int index) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
          style: _titleStyle(index),
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: widget.steps[index].title,
        ),
        if (widget.steps[index].subtitle != null)
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
            child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
              style: _subtitleStyle(index),
              duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: widget.steps[index].subtitle!,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLabelText(int index) {
    if (widget.steps[index].label != null) {
      return AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
        style: _labelStyle(index),
        duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
        child: widget.steps[index].label!,
      );
    }
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }

  Widget _buildVerticalHeader(int index) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildLine(!_isFirst(index)),
              _buildIcon(index),
              _buildLine(!_isLast(index)),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
              child: _buildHeaderText(index),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildVerticalBody(int index) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PositionedDirectional(
          start: 24.0,
          top: 0.0,
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 24.0,
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _isLast(index) ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                child: Container(
                  color: widget.lineColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedCrossFade(
          firstChild: Container(height: 0.0),
          secondChild: Container(
            margin: widget.margin ??
                const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                  start: 60.0,
                  end: 24.0,
                  bottom: 24.0,
                ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                widget.steps[index].content,
                _buildVerticalControls(index),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          firstCurve: const Interval(0.0, 0.6, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
          secondCurve: const Interval(0.4, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
          sizeCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          crossFadeState: _isCurrent(index)
              ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
              : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildVertical() {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: widget.physics,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1)
          Column(
            key: _keys[i],
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: widget.steps[i].state != CusStepState.disabled
                    ? () {
                        // In the vertical case we need to scroll to the newly tapped
                        // step.
                        Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                          _keys[i].currentContext!,
                          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                        );

                        widget.onStepTapped?.call(i);
                      }
                    : null,
                canRequestFocus: widget.steps[i].state != CusStepState.disabled,
                child: _buildVerticalHeader(i),
              ),
              _buildVerticalBody(i),
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHorizontal() {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[
      for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1) ...<Widget>[
        InkResponse(
          onTap: widget.steps[i].state != CusStepState.disabled
              ? () {
                  widget.onStepTapped?.call(i);
                }
              : null,
          canRequestFocus: widget.steps[i].state != CusStepState.disabled,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: _isLabel() ? 104.0 : 72.0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    if (widget.steps[i].label != null)
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 24.0,
                      ),
                    Center(child: _buildIcon(i)),
                    if (widget.steps[i].label != null)
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 24.0,
                        child: _buildLabelText(i),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
                child: _buildHeaderText(i),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        if (!_isLast(i))
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              height: 1.0,
              color: widget.lineColor,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ];

    final List<Widget> stepPanels = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1) {
      stepPanels.add(
        Visibility(
          maintainState: true,
          visible: i == widget.currentStep,
          child: widget.steps[i].content,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Material(
          elevation: widget.elevation ?? 2,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
            child: Row(
              children: children,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            physics: widget.physics,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: stepPanels),
              ),
              _buildVerticalControls(widget.currentStep),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterial(context));
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    assert(() {
      if (context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Stepper>() != null) {
        throw FlutterError(
          'Steppers must not be nested.\n'
          'The material specification advises that one should avoid embedding '
          'steppers within steppers. '
          'https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html#steppers-usage',
        );
      }
      return true;
    }());
    switch (widget.type) {
      case CusStepperType.vertical:
        return _buildVertical();
      case CusStepperType.horizontal:
        return _buildHorizontal();
    }
  }
}

class _TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  _TrianglePainter({
    required this.color,
  });

  final Color color;

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset point) => true;
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_TrianglePainter oldPainter) {
    return oldPainter.color != color;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double base = size.width;
    final double halfBase = size.width / 2.0;
    final double height = size.height;
    final List<Offset> points = <Offset>[
      Offset(0.0, height),
      Offset(base, height),
      Offset(halfBase, 0.0),
    ];

    canvas.drawPath(
      Path()..addPolygon(points, true),
      Paint()..color = color,
    );
  }
}
```

**EXAMPLE CODEBASE ON HOW TO USE THE `CusStepper`**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tester/stepper/stepper.dart'; // this is the file path of where you store your `cusStepper`

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Tester',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CusStepper(
          lineColor: Colors.red, // new line add for the color change
          currentStep: _index,
          onStepCancel: () {
            if (_index > 0) {
              setState(() {
                _index -= 1;
              });
            }
          },
          onStepContinue: () {
            if (_index <= 0) {
              setState(() {
                _index += 1;
              });
            }
          },
          onStepTapped: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _index = index;
            });
          },
          steps: <CusStep>[
            CusStep(
              title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
              content: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: const Text('Content for Step 1')),
            ),
            const CusStep(
              title: Text('Step 2 title'),
              content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: gif for the output]

Leave a comment below if you have any questions or help on this.
Bye!

Comment: here Question is Change Stapper between line color change.  
grey to another color.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I only want to Change the stepper line color flutter. Look at the picture of q. please

Comment: I just updated the answer. The short answer is, **"not possible at the moment"**. Check my edited answer for more info on why.

Comment: @JEMISHVASOYA I just updated the answer. Feel free to review it! Thanks

Comment: it's not working please check and run this because you post an old code that not working now.

Comment: @HoRiz Check out my updated answer. I just made a custom `Stepper` based on your requirements.

Comment: @JEMISHVASOYA check out the custom `Stepper` and let me know if anything is missing. Thanks